# Android: Interacting with 3rd-party app

Tags: android, interaction

I am wondering if it is possible to launch a 3rd-party application from within my own application.  I understand that Android runs in a sandbox, and so I am not too optimistic about this being possible.

I read the following here: http://source.android.com/tech/security/index.html:

> "This sets up a kernel-level Application Sandbox. The kernel enforces security between applications and the system at the process level through standard Linux facilities, such as user and group IDs that are assigned to applications. By default, applications cannot interact with each other and applications have limited access to the operating system. If application A tries to do something malicious like read application B's data or dial the phone without permission (which is a separate application), then the operating system protects against this because application A does not have the appropriate user privileges. The sandbox is simple, auditable, and based on decades-old UNIX-style user separation of processes and file permissions."

Essentially, I want to launch some 3rd-party application that can scan and decode a barcode, and then have that data available to my own application.  As I said, I doubt that this is possible, but surely someone must have encountered this before, and maybe found a compromise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible if you have appropriate permissions to do that. Lot of applications use that feature to avoid writing the feature in their own app. Look into content providers as you are asking another content provider to scan barcode an provide you the data.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Thanks, this seems like it should work.  However, I found a very simple solution to my specific problem, which can be found here: [ZXing](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/)